# SpringXD Error when deploying Stream: StringDeserializer class could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

I'm configuring my custom kafka source and I'm getting an error related to the     `value.deserializer` kafka property.

This is the config that I have:

```
<!--Consumer -->
<bean id="container1"
    class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="false" />
                    <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="100" />
                    <entry key="session.timeout.ms" value="15000" />
                    <entry key="group.id" value="bridge-stream-testing" />
                    <entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer" />
                    <entry key="value.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
```

I see `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer` class indeed (I can click the class name and it takes me to the jar file.

Just in case this is the content in my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xd-module-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ejemplos.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-source-latest-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>pentaho-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

These are the logs that I'm getting: https://gist.github.com/columb1a/2833f1ac751436df1caa730ce1a0eb37

Answer (score 1):

Try to place `kafka-clients` jar into the shared `/lib` instead of module classpath. I just guess, but looks like that class is tried to be load by the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();` instead of module-specific.

Comment: you are talking about `xd/lib`, right? Then, Should I update just the `kafka-clients` jar, or everything related to kafka?

Comment: How about just to try for small steps ? I mean, let's start from Kafka, first of all!

Comment: Ok, in fact that is what I tried like 30 mins ago. But Now I'm getting new errors. Let me restore everything and just change `kafka-clients` jar first.

Comment: After just updated the `kafka-clients` that is located within `xd/lib` I'm getting  this error: https://gist.github.com/columb1a/07bb4f3da92f42bc9ad746c382091778. There's another folder within the `xd/lib`folder called  `Kafka` . There's another copy of `kafka-clients`, I will update it as well just in case, but I don't understand what the purpose of that folder is.

Comment: I think that one is for `KafkaMessageBus`

Comment: I think I resolved my problem. After having replaced the `kafka-clients` **PLUS** having added `provided`scope to the `kafka-clients` dependency, my consumer is working properly (so far).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem as follows: After having replaced the `kafka-clients` **PLUS** having added `provided` scope to the `kafka-clients` dependency in my pom file, my consumer is working properly (so far).